# In which coordinates (x, y, z) are vertical grids expressed?

Tags: coordinates, grids-graticules, xy, xyz, terminology

When working with 2D maps, coordinates are always expressed in X and Y. Adding a 3rd dimension also adds the Z-coordinate, which typically stands for height.

However, when working with vertical grids (for measurements, visualizations on building facades or the sides of 3D polygons, etc.) I don't know which coordinates to mention in order to express what I mean.

Is it 'X and Z' or 'Y and Z'? Or does it become 'X and Y' again since there is no 3rd dimension?

Comment: Are you using MapInfo or something else?

Comment: Currently im using a mix of ArcScene, ArcMap and GeoMilieu (for noise calculations). I dont need the coordinates for calculations or modelling, but just for expressing things in a written report.

Comment: You could treat each plane (wall, roof, floor) as if it has a local X,Y coordinate system, but you would have to show the orientation for each one. However, if you use the overall coordinate system, (X,Y,Z) of the scene, a wall or a floor, unless directly parallel to two of the axes, could have all 3 components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of such analysis/presentation is to only locate/reference/measure things inside the perimeter of each plane individually, then yes, treat those as a 2D map with a [Cartesian Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), hence, adopting standard X and Y terminology to designate the local coordinates.

On the other hand, use traditional X, Y and Z terminology if any georeferencing is needed or for positioning/presenting all planes together in the 3D space.